# When does a shared library have to be on the Java classpath?

Tags: java, shared-libraries, jna, .so

I'm trying to work with a third-party SDK on RHEL. Running this vendor's sample code (using their own provided run.sh) throws what I'll call Error 1: `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'redacted': Native library (linux-x86-64/libredacted.so) not found in resource path`. I add the library location to the class path, and that error disappears.

It is replaced with Error 2: `Java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: libodbc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`, where I obviously am missing a dependency. I install the appropriate MySQL package (which puts the .so in /lib64) and it's happy.

Now both .so files are in /lib64, which is on the Java library path, so I would assume it should find them the same. Even pointing `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the library (which the vendor had done in their script) doesn't resolve Error 1.

**Why is the first library required to be on the class path when Java uses java.library.path to find shared objects?**

It's worth noting that the vendor's script didn't run correctly out of the box, which makes me wonder if it's an issue with my particular RHEL installation.

Comment: didn't you ask this question 4 days back?

Comment: Admittedly, yes. It had single-digit views and no interaction whatsoever, which I attribute to asking late on a Friday afternoon. I added details/tags and deleted the old one to avoid duplicates. If I still get no answers this time around, fine, but I didn't want it to be for virtue of posting at a bad time

Comment: Does this question concern JNA's `Native.loadLibrary` or Java's `System.load`?